# Select rows as column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 name  | value  | product_id 
-------+--------+------------
 color | red    |          9
 style | modern |          9
 brand | xxx    |          1
 color | blue   |          4
 color | red    |          1
```

How to select product ids, where brand = xxx and color = red? This is product with id=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id FROM tbl WHERE "name"='color' AND "value"='red'
INTERSECT
SELECT product_id FROM tbl WHERE "name"='brand' AND "value"='xxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T
WHERE name = 'color' 
AND value = 'red'
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
            WHERE name = 'brand'
            AND value = 'xxx'
            AND product_id = T.product_id)
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't understand the question.